# Python Regex Repeating Same Match Multiple Times

Tags: python, regex

Scenario:

I am opening up an XML file as text by using `open('name of file', 'r')`

I am searching for a specific pattern.

Despite the fact that there is only 1 line in the xml document that has the pattern that I am looking for, I get it returned multiple times.

I know that it only appears once because I created the file myself. I am only picking up 1 file.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
src_q_regex = re.compile('\[sales\]\.\[customer\]', re.IGNORECASE)


for a in range(0, len(ssis_txt_files_2)):

    open_sample_file = open(ssis_txt_files_2[a], 'r')

    whatever = open_sample_file.readlines()
    whatever = ''.join(whatever)

   #for x in range(0,len(whatever), 1):
    for x in range(0,10, 1):
        source_found = src_q_regex.search(whatever)
        if source_found:

            thing = str(source_found.group())
            print(str(thing))
```

Here is the output:

```
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
[Sales].[Customer]
```

What I want it to return:

```
`[Sales].[Customer]`   <---just 1 time because that is the only number of times it appears.
```

**Edit #1:**

I removed the word 'hi' as I was using it just to test and replaced it with the actual variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping 10 times with `for x in range(0,10, 1):`

So the single match is printed 10 times.

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping 10 times and printing output 10 times.

```
for x in range(0,10, 1):
    source_found = src_q_regex.search('hi')
    if source_found:
        thing = str(source_found.group())
        print(str(thing))
```

Just remove the loop:

```
src_q_regex = re.compile('\[sales\]\.\[customer\]', re.IGNORECASE)


for a in range(0, len(ssis_txt_files_2)):

    open_sample_file = open(ssis_txt_files_2[a], 'r')

    whatever = open_sample_file.readlines()
    whatever = ''.join(whatever)

    source_found = src_q_regex.search('hi')
    if source_found:
        thing = str(source_found.group())
        print(str(thing))
```

Comment: I see it, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!